# Problem with install "links" in virtual box

Tags: 14.04, playonlinux

My Os already is Windows so I connected to Linux Ubuntu with virtual box, now I've installed " links " but not be installed. This result demonstrates to us :

> sudo apt-get install links

```
reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package links
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `links` package is in the universe repository. Is it enabled on your system? Does `grep -E "^deb.*universe" /etc/apt/sources.list` give any output?

Comment: actually, I install the Snap.
thank u for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grep -E "^deb.*universe" /etc/apt/sources.list (from DK Bose)

```
sudo snap install links
```